# How to delete a component entirely in Angular 2

Tags: angular

I created a component using ng g compoment command but I now I want to delete it. I deleted the entire component folder, plus the reference in the app.module.ts file, the html file. Still the project gives me this error:

```
client?93b6:101 TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined
    at createSourceFile (C:\Users\Me\Desktop\Super-CardAngular\node_modules\typescript\lib\typescript.js:8980:110)
    at parseSourceFileWorker (C:\Users\Me\Desktop\Super-CardAngular\node_modules\typescript\lib\typescript.js:8940:26)
    at Object.parseSourceFile (C:\Users\Me\Desktop\Super-CardAngular\node_modules\typescript\lib\typescript.js:8899:26)
    at Object.createSourceFile (C:\Users\Me\Desktop\Super-CardAngular\node_modules\typescript\lib\typescript.js:8727:29)
    at new TypeScriptFileRefactor (C:\Users\Me\Desktop\Super-CardAngular\node_modules\@ngtools\webpack\src\refactor.js:79:35)
    at Object.findLazyRoutes (C:\Users\Me\Desktop\Super-CardAngular\node_modules\@ngtools\webpack\src\lazy_routes.js:18:22)
    at AotPlugin._findLazyRoutesInAst (C:\Users\Me\Desktop\Super-CardAngular\node_modules\@ngtools\webpack\src\plugin.js:216:50)
    at _donePromise.Promise.resolve.then.then.then.then.then (C:\Users\Me\Desktop\Super-CardAngular\node_modules\@ngtools\webpack\src\plugin.js:494:24)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:68:7)
errors @ client?93b6:101
```

I went inside the typescript folder and to the suggested line and there is no error there. I checked most of the files but I still can't find where the error is. What else should I delete? What other files need to be changed in order to delete fully my component

Comment: Did you rebuild/restart the app?

Comment: Are you sure that this error derives from the deleted component? It could also be located somewhere else. If you have referenced the component in other places of your application, you should delete those references aswell.

Comment: I had a very similar error the other day that was a result of removing some of the `environment.<env>.ts` files, but still referencing them in `.angular-cli.json`

Comment: I restarted the app and it compiled without any errors. I was expecting that after I have done the changes it would still run without a need for rebuilding.

Answer (score 0):

firstly manually goes to: **App.module.ts**
and do those steps:

### Delete:

```
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';


and delete here:
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
```

Hope I will have helped you.